# Simple compile error but doesn't make sense

Tags: c++, class, hierarchy

Here are all of the .cpp and .h files being used in the result of my errors. They are errors i have seen and fixed before but i don't understand why i'm getting these errors, it wouldn't make the right syntax for the code.

shape.h

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

using std::cout; using std::cerr; using std::endl;
using std::string;
    class Shape{
      public:
    Shape(const string&)  { } //default constructor
    virtual void print() const;
    virtual double get_area() const;
    virtual ~Shape();
      private:
    string color;
    };
#endif
```

shape.cpp

```
#include "shape.h"
using std::cout; using std::cerr; using std::endl;
using std::string;
void Shape::print() const{
cout << color << endl; }
Shape::Shape(const string& color1):color(color1)
{/*color = color1;*/ }
Shape::~Shape()
{ }
```

circle.h

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "shape.h"
using namespace std;
using std::cout; using std::cerr; using std::endl;
using std::string; using std::vector;
class Circle : public Shape{
  public:
  Circle(const string& , int); 
virtual void print() const;
virtual double get_area() const;
  private:
int radius;
};
#endif
```

circle.cpp

```
 #include "circle.h"
using std::cout; using std::cerr; using std::endl;
using std::string;
Circle::Circle(const string& color1,int newRadius):Shape(color1),radius(newRadius) {}

double Circle::get_area() const{
double area;
area = M_PI * (pow(radius,2) );
return area;
}

void Circle::print() const{
cout << "Circle: " <<
     << color << " circle, "
     << "radius " << radius << ", "
     << "area " << get_area() << endl;
}
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"
#include "circle.h"
#include <vector>
using std::vector; using std::string;
using namespace std;
int main{

    vector<Shape *> shape1(1);
    shape1[0] = new Circle("Green",20);

/*
for(int i = 0; i < arr; i++ )
i.print();

for(int i = 0; i < arr; i++ )
delete [] arr;
*/
 return 0;
```

errors:

```
    assign9.cpp:9:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘shape1’
 vector<Shape *> shape1(1);
                 ^
assign9.cpp:9:17: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘shape1’
assign9.cpp:9:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘shape1’
assign9.cpp:10:1: error: ‘shape1’ does not name a type
 shape1[0] = new Circle("Green",20);
 ^
assign9.cpp:19:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
  return 0;
  ^
assign9.cpp:20:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 }

^
```

I'm not understanding how these errors are coming about, even my TA couldn't figure it out. I appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're missing some header includes.

Comment: Have you added 'using std;' directive? You have to, if you're using string and vector without std:: specified.

Comment: Typo. You have `class Cirlce` instead of `class Circle`. `l` and `c` are swapped by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cirlce instead of Circle.

string instead of std::string.

On a side note, the constructor for Circle should better be
    Circle::Circle(const string& color1, int newRadius):Shape(color1), radius(newRadius) {}

(initialize everything you can in constructors rather than in brackets).

Comment: Terminology note: Where you say "in constructors" better wording would be "in the member initializer list".

Comment: Thanks for the side note, i fixed the Cirlce instead of Circle, but the exact same error occur.

Comment: I tried it. Your code have lot of errors, but this same error does not occur. Maybe you forgot to save the file. If it still occurs, create the minimum example (try to create one file where it occurs, combining all your files together; then make the file as small as possible, removing everything which is unneccessary for error reproduction).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. And I'm also using my terminal for this

Comment: Do you still have the very same error?

Comment: I'm using turing, and yes i am still having same error

Comment: Learn what the minimal example is.

Comment: I figured out my problems. my first problem was that i had 'int main{ ' instead of 'int main(){ '. I had forgotten the parenthesis. silly mistake. and I solved my errors. Thank you for your advice!